# Pandas - Convert list of numpy arrays into one single list?

Tags: python, numpy

When trying to implement OneHotEncoding into my machine learning project, I am using the following code to encode my 3 category features (job, marital status & education)

```
encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories = 'auto')
feature_array = encoder.fit_transform(df[['job', 'marital', 'education']]).toarray()
feature_labels = encoder.categories_
```

This returns the categories for each of the 3 features into 3 different arrays captured in a list.

```
[array(['admin.', 'blue-collar', 'management', 'retired', 'self-employed',
        'services', 'student', 'technician', 'unemployed', 'unknown'],
       dtype=object),
 array(['divorced', 'married', 'single'], dtype=object),
 array(['primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary', 'unknown'], dtype=object)]
```

I understand that using a for loop through this list can return 3 lists containing the labels for all 3 features,

```
for value in feature_labels:
    print(value)

['admin.' 'blue-collar' 'management' 'retired' 'self-employed' 'services'
 'student' 'technician' 'unemployed' 'unknown']
['divorced' 'married' 'single']
['primary' 'secondary' 'tertiary' 'unknown']
```

That being said, is there a more elegant or one liner that I can incorporate to create a list containing all the various categories for my 3 features? In the end, I'd love to have a single list that looks the one below so I can pipe in all 3 encoded features into a single dataframe,

```
['admin.', 'blue-collar', 'management', 'retired', 'self-employed', 'services', 'student' ,'technician', 'unemployed', 'unknown', 'divorced', 'married', 'single', 'primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary', 'unknown']
```

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy's concatenate to join your 3 arrays: (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```
labels = np.concatenate(feature_labels)

# The result:
array(['admin.', 'blue-collar', 'management', 'retired', 'self-employed',
       'services', 'student', 'technician', 'unemployed', 'unknown',
       'divorced', 'married', 'single', 'primary', 'secondary',
       'tertiary', 'unknown'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

If You have nested list:

```
l = [['admin.', 'blue-collar', 'management', 'retired', 'self-employed','services', 'student', 'technician', 'unemployed', 'unknown'],\
['divorced', 'married', 'single'], ['primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary', 'unknown']]
```

one of method to unnest it is:

```
import itertools

flat_l  = list(itertools.chain(*l))
```

result:

```
['admin.',
 'blue-collar',
 'management',
 'retired',
 'self-employed',
 'services',
 'student',
 'technician',
 'unemployed',
 'unknown',
 'divorced',
 'married',
 'single',
 'primary',
 'secondary',
 'tertiary',
 'unknown']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a list of numpy arrays you could also use:

```
import numpy as np

l = list(np.concatenate(feature_labels))
```